# how to detect pressed button from 2d array of buttons in ontouchlistener

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a grid view on which 2d array of buttons is placed. i have set ontouchlistener on gird view. when first button is touched, how can i use if statement in the grid view ontouchlistener to detect if the button[0][0] is pressed/touched

```
    gv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int actionPeformed = event.getAction();

            switch(actionPeformed) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    final float x = event.getX();
                    final float y = event.getY();

                    lastXAxis = x;
                    lastYAxis = y;
                    textView2.setText("Button pressed");

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    final float x = event.getX();
                    final float y = event.getY();

                    final float dx = x - lastXAxis;
                    final float dy = y - lastYAxis;
                    ed4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                    xAxis += dx;
                    yAxis += dy;
                    ed4.setText(Float.toString(yAxis));
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                    textView2.setText("released");

                }
```

when button[0][0] is pressed, the color of button should change. similarly if buttons[0][0] and [0][1] is pressed then color of both buttons should change. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling something like this to get the view of the button being pressed.
Once you have the button view being pressed/released it should be easy enough to change its color

```
    private Button getTouchedButton(MotionEvent event) {
        for(int i=0; i<myGridView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            Rect buttonRect = new Rect()
            Button child = (Button)mGridView.getChildAt(i);
            child.getHitRect(buttonRect)
            if (child.contains(Math.round(event.rawX), Math.round(event.rawY))){
                return child;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: what does this if statement mean?

Comment: i understood your code, but after getting child elements of grid view how can i check if the child element is pressed or not. i tried if(buttons[0][0].isPressed()) but isPressed() did not work @luca992

Comment: The if statement checks if the x y coordinate of a touch is inside the space occupied by a button on the screen. 

So, if you call this function inside of MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN or MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE it will return the button which is being touched. Otherwise, it will be null. 

buttons[0][0].isPressed() is probably not working because the touch listener you added to your grid view is probably consuming the touch event thus the gridview's children never receive the touch events.... But I don't know because you didn't post what your on touch listener returns

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if(button[0][0].getId() == R.id.buttonIDInXML) { }
```

View.getId() return int value which means ID that you set in xml files. Button is also view, so this could be helpful to you I guess.

Comment: i have created 2d array of buttons in java. there is no id of buttons in xml file

Comment: No Id in R.id.* ?? Really? Then.... `Clean project` - `Rebuild project`